# Was the priority betwen operator an abitrary decision?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

this morning in the shower a question came to me.
Was the priority betwen operator (* comes before +) an arbitrary decision or it can't be done otherwhise?

I think it's an arbitrary decision, if we choosed to do + before * we would get the same result but we would write differently.

But I'm no mathematician.

Comment: That decision lies so far back in time, and is so deeply embedded in our culture, it is hard to say what the thinking was. But I think that sums of products are more common than products of sums, therefore the current convention is much more convenient.

Comment: Note that the Windows calculator will follow one priority convention in standard mode, and a different one in scientific mode...$2+3\times5=25 or 17$

Comment: There are programming languages (like APL) which have no operator precedence at all, and they vary among languages (but not between `+` and `*`). Yes, it is arbitrary.